# I'm always get -1 index in java arraylist

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;


public class SWDistaster extends ITDisaster
{
    String Cause; int count=0;
    List<String> SW_NameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> SW_PlaceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Double> SW_CostList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Integer> SW_DateList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public SWDistaster() {}
    public SWDistaster(String Name)
    {
        super(Name);
    }
    public void show() 
    {
        System.out.println(Name + " " + Place + " " + Cost + " " + Date + " " + Cause);

    }

    public void SW_SearchName(String name)
    {
        System.out.println(SW_NameList.lastIndexOf(name));
        if(SW_NameList.contains(name)) 
        {
            System.out.println(SW_PlaceList.get(SW_NameList.indexOf(name)));
            System.out.println("here");
        } 
        else
        {
            SW_NameList(name);
            //System.out.println("here2");
        }
    }
    public void SW_NameList(String name)
    {
        SW_NameList.add(count, name);
        count++;
    }
    public void SW_PlaceList(String place)
    {
        SW_PlaceList.add(place);
    }
    public void SW_CostList(double cost)
    {
        SW_CostList.add(cost);
    }
    public void SW_DateList(int date)
    {
        SW_DateList.add(date);
    }
    public void ShowList()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<SW_NameList.size() ; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print((SW_NameList.get(i)).toString());
        }  
    }
}
```

and application class :

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SWDistaster dis1 = new SWDistaster();
        dis1.SW_SearchName("Election");
        dis1.ShowList();
        SWDistaster dis2 = new SWDistaster();
        dis2.SW_SearchName("Election");
        dis2.ShowList();
        SWDistaster dis3 = new SWDistaster();
        dis3.SW_SearchName("Batee5");
        dis3.ShowList();
    }
}
```

there is no append in arraylist like i'm always used to do in vector in c++ !
and i need to save all names in arraylist to come and search in and if i find it i would show the place and date and if not i will add it to the arraylist
and may anybody also help me how to use files to save in it more easily as i'm new to java

Comment: wrongAnswer has the rightAnswer!

Comment: Lol ;) that a paradox !!!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the java doc for lastIndexOf [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))

```
public int lastIndexOf(String str,
          int fromIndex)
```

Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

The returned index is the largest value k for which:

```
k <= fromIndex && this.startsWith(str, k)
```

**If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.**

Parameters:

str - the substring to search for.

fromIndex - the index to start the search from.

Returns:
the index of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward from the specified index, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

Comment: sorry i cant understand u :)

Comment: If the function lastIndexOf cannot find the required string it will return -1.

Comment: i'm using this only for testing !

Comment: I cannot understand your question any more .

Comment: i need to append to araylist 
when i used three objects and show what in arraylist it give me only the object only 
why not all the arraylist ?

Comment: As simple as List<String> SW_NameList = new ArrayList<String>();SW_NameList.add("Election");SW_NameList.add("Election");SW_NameList.add("Batee");

            Also remove the .toString from System.out.print((SW_NameList.get(i)).toString()); it should be        System.out.print(SW_NameList.get(i));

Comment: i need to be in the main not in function how could i do that !

Comment: Sorry the answer to that is too broad please read on class & objects. The read on ArrayList and how to use it... I cannot add the answer to that in a comment.